# Extracting Values from string using spirit parser

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

i have following line 
**/90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C usecmap**

```
std::string const line = "/90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C usecmap";

auto first = line.begin(), last = line.end();

std::string label, token;
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
        first, last, 
        qi::lexeme [ "/" >> +~qi::char_(" ") ] >> ' ' >>  qi::lexeme[+~qi::char_(' ')] , qi::space, label, token);


if (ok)
    std::cout << "Parse success: label='" << label << "', token='" << token << "'\n";
else
    std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

if (first!=last)
    std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";
```

I want to **90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C in label** and **usecmap** in token variable.

I extract 90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C value but not usecmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `space` the skipper, you cannot ever match `' '` (it is skipped!). See also: [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)

So, either don't use a skipper, or allow the skipper to eat it:

```
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
        first, last, 
        qi::lexeme [ "/" >> +qi::graph ] >> qi::lexeme[+qi::graph], qi::blank, label, token);
```

Notes:

- I used `qi::graph` instead of the `~qi::char_(" ")` formulation
- I used `blank_type` because you said

  > *i have following line*

  Which implies that line-ends should not be skipped

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bb81d2bda3d0a91)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::string const line = "/90pv-rksj-ucs2c usecmap";

    auto first = line.begin(), last = line.end();

    std::string label, token;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
            first, last, 
            qi::lexeme [ "/" >> +qi::graph ] >> qi::lexeme[+qi::graph], qi::blank, label, token);

    if (ok)
        std::cout << "parse success: label='" << label << "', token='" << token << "'\n";
    else
        std::cout << "parse failed\n";

    if (first!=last)
        std::cout << "remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
parse success: label='90pv-rksj-ucs2c', token='usecmap'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11, I suggest using regular expression.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    regex re("^/([^\\s]*)\\s([^\\s]*)"); // 1st () captures
                                         // 90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C and 2nd () captures usecmap
    smatch sm;
    string s="/90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C usecmap";
    regex_match(s,sm,re);
    for(int i=0;i<sm.size();i++) {
        cout<<sm[i]<<endl;
    }
    string label=sm[1],token=sm[2];
    system("pause");
}
```